# Maximum number of edges on a uniform hypergraph

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs, hypergraphs

I need to find the maximum number of hyperedges that can be drawn in a hypergraph, such that,

1. There are $8$ vertices.
2. Every edge contains exactly $4$ vertices.
3. Every edge should have exactly $2$ vertices in common with every other edge.

I got the answer to be $7$ by brute force. I believe there's a more elegant solution. If I were to name these criteria as the $8-4-2$ graph, then my aim is to generalize the solution to $16-8-4, 32-16-8,$ etc. Thanks in advance

Comment: By definition, an edge connects two vertices. What then do you mean with points 2 and 3? Are you sure you are using the terms edge and vertex correctly?

Comment: Are you maybe talking about [block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design)?

Comment: I meant hyperedges and hypergraphs

Comment: The argument I gave for the upper bound in the answer I posted [the last time you asked this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829628/find-the-edges-in-a-hypergraph) (you're welcome) generalizes to show that a $4n-2n-n$ graph has at most $$\left\lfloor\frac{\binom{4n}{n+1}}{2\binom{2n}{n+1}}\right\rfloor$$ edges. (The same argument works for any positive integer $n$, though you are only interested in the case where $n$ is a power of $2$.) In particular a $16-8-4$ graph can't have more than $39$ edges. I have no idea whether this bound can be attained.